# How to open files from Ubuntu on Windows in Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed Ubuntu on Windows for Ruby on Rails development and when I create Rails project I want to open it in VS Code. So I type `code .` in bash to open the current folder in VS Code. But instead, it opens system32 in VS Code.

Can I even open the project from bash like that? If not, what is the correct way?

Comment: It probably has something to do with WSL and how it operates. When I try `code .` on my Linux desktop, it opens current directory as expected. Maybe try it with the full path or use `code --help`. There are some options which look usable for your case, like `--folder-uri`

Comment: It works for me as well `code .` in linux desktop but in WSL no, I tried `code --folder-uri` but still nothing.

Comment: I used the following guide to accomplish what you are describing: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl